# Figcaption width not fitting the image - 'width: fit-content' ineffective

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the 'text here' caption to have the same width as the image. I've added `width: fit-content` to the caption but it ignores it and sets a width to the text content.

How can this be fixed? Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for any help.

```css
img {
  max-width: 488px;
  width: 526px;
  max-height: 338px;
}
figure {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
figcaption {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 85%;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img border="0" height="364" src="https://media.cntraveler.com/photos/5a0efefba15d3804847cb88b/master/w_1200,c_limit/elephant-vid-tout.jpg">
  <figcaption>Text Here</figcaption></figure>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1k6fmctr/ - here is the text and image the same width. you need to set the width of the figcaption to match the image

Comment: what about when the image will be different in size? how can the width: fit-content be used?

Comment: any other ideas anyone? I'd rather not have to use a table to solve this

Answer (score 1):

The caption width has no method of *knowing*  the width of the image.

There is a method using `table` layout.

```css
img {
  max-width: 488px;
  width: 526px;
  max-height: 338px;
  display: block;
}

figure {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  width: 1%;
}

figcaption {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 85%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img border="0" height="364" src="https://media.cntraveler.com/photos/5a0efefba15d3804847cb88b/master/w_1200,c_limit/elephant-vid-tout.jpg">
  <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati excepturi maiores saepe temporibus libero consequuntur rem, nemo repellat adipisci ea?</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Nope... `fit-content` would be as wide as the paragraph is...not the image.

Comment: but there is no paragraph - I thought width: fit-content was supposed to match the width of the content

Comment: paragraph = figcaption...and it will be as wide as the text willl let it. In this case, wider than the image.